# underscore template selector

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I use underscore templates, to render my page. The problem starts when I use:

```
$(function(){
   console.log($('.input-placeholder'));
});
```

and I can access them sometimes, sometimes it just doesn't work because the page gets rendered after the document load.

So I use

```
$('#application').html(_.template('<div class="input-placeholder"></div>', {}));
```

And it sometimes prints to console that it found input-placeholder but not all the time. How can I make sure that after the template is loaded the $(function(){}) is triggered.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/

Read the template in the render method:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function(){
    var html = _.template($("#my-template"));
    this.$el.html(html);
  }
});
```

And then wait until after the DOMReady event has fired before starting your app, creating your view instance and rendering it.

Comment: If it's not a one off template then you probably don't want to recompile the template for every view that needs that template.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you could try this alternative to Derick's solution.

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    el: document.createElement('div'),
    template: null,
    render: function(){
        if(this.template === null){
            this.template = _.template($('#my-template'));
        }
        this.$el.html(this.template({}));
    }
});
```

Please note that if you do:

```
var something = _.template('<div><%= haha %></div>');
```

`something` becomes a function that gives you html when you give it data, you shouldn't recompile every time.